# Convert a piped operator sequence into an R function or similar (ideally using Tidyverse)

Tags: r, function, dictionary

### I'm trying to convert a piped operator sequence into an R function or similar (ideally using Tidyverse).

The input is a tidy dataframe with the responses to 15 questions as variables and each of the 10 observations are one of 4 standard responses (e.g. agree, disagree, etc.)

The output should be a summary of responses with both a count and percentage of the distribution of responses/observations for each question/variable.

To avoid copying and pasting and to improve the code, I would like to wrap a function or similar to calculate the count and percentages in a loop, Purr map or similar to iterate over the 15 questions.

Thank you for your suggestions.

---

The below code works as expected and responds with a table of Question , Count  and Percentage  with values for Agree, etc. This is ultimately what I am trying to achieve on scale and elegantly.

```
DF %>%
  select(question) %>%
  group_by(question) %>%
  summarise(Count = n()) %>%
  mutate (Percentage = round(100 * Count / sum(Count),0))
```

---

**Background**

I start with a tidy dataframe:

```
*'data.frame':  10 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Question1                   : Factor w/ 4 levels "Agree","Neither agree nor disagree",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...*
```

The following gets me close, without the percentages:

```
DF_as_list <- DF %>%
  map(summary)
```

by creating

```
 *List of 15
 $ Question1                   : Named int [1:4] 10 0 0 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Agree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Disagree" "Don't know"*
```

And the less helpful

```
> DF_from_list<- data.frame(matrix(unlist(DF_as_list),
> nrow=length(DF_as_list), byrow=T))
```

creates:

```
*'data.frame':  15 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ X1: int  10 10 ...
 $ X2: int  0 0 ...
 $ X3: int  0 0 ...
 $ X4: int  0 0 ...*
```

Finally,

```
DF_as_tibble <- as_tibble(DF_as_list)
```

produces a helpful summary tibble

```
*Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  15 variables:
 $ Question1                   : int  10 0 0 0
 $ Question2                   : int  10 0 0 0*
```

and

```
DF_as_tibble %>%
  map(summary)
```

produces useful summary statistics (min, median, mean, max, 1st and 3rd Qu) but not the percentage distribution of responses.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To make it easier for people to help you, please include a sample of data in the same format as yours, ideally including the output of `dput(YOUR_DATA)` in the body of your question.